# Citing/referring (markup?) to another user on TeX.SX

Tags: discussion

Sometimes, I find necessary, predominantly in a comment, to give some users name and refer to a solution that user has made, which could be helpful in post under consideration too.

I am unsure, how to markup the other's name properly.

For example, if there is a user called 'GandalfTheGray', what would be a good way to refer to her/him, e.g.

In his example, user

- **GandalfTheGray**
- *GandalfTheGray*
- *`GandalfTheGray`*
- [GandalfTheGray]
- "GandalfTheGray"
- **`GandalfTheGray`**
- `{GandalfTheGray}`

shows/comments/hints .... etc.

Are there some other markup possibilities? I personally find the bold version too strong, and the slanted version too weak, my favorite is *`GandalfTheGray`*.

What do you think?

This is no question on a feature-request, just my personal interest to make references to other people more outstanding in a post/comment.

Comment: You could also link the corresponding user profile: [Christian Hupfer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/31729/christian-hupfer)

Comment: @Johannes_B: Yes, that is a possibility, I was also thinking about that, but on the other hand, the profile is in this case not that important, isn't it?

Comment: ok, right; if you want to link to a special solution, you can also link the answer itself: [Answer by CH](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/171585/37907)

Comment: @Johannes_B: Ok, a direct link to some answer with the correct anchor, that could do ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would leave it as just plain unformatted text. Personally, I don't consider it necessary (or particularly useful) to distinguish names from the surrounding text with formatting; it's already clear from the context what the display name is. The only exception is, in a comment (not a question or answer), when I want to notify that user, if they have left a previous comment and are thus eligible for notification, then I will use @GandalfTheGray.

When I want to reference another user's contribution, I will link to that post directly. For example:

> Christian Hupfer posted a good [question about markup for usernames](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4535/citing-referring-markup-to-another-user-on-tex-sx)

If one wants to access the poster's profile, they can click through to the post and then to the profile.

---

So that this is not merely a statement of opinion: in posts I see other people make, display names are *very rarely* formatted any differently than the surrounding text.